# Input field date in format DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I am using Regex to automatically convert the date in the format of DD-MM-YYYY for an input field. It is working as I want but the problem is the cursor moves 1 character behind after the first "-". I have to manually move the cursor 1 step forward and then start typing again. I want the cursor to come at the end of the text. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using TMPro;

public class InputDateMask : MonoBehaviour {
    public TMP_InputField inputField;

    private void Awake () {
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener (delegate { OnValueChanged (); });
    }

    public void OnValueChanged () {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (inputField.text)) {
            inputField.text = string.Empty;
        } else {
            string input = inputField.text;
            string MatchPattern = @"^((\d{2}-){0,2}(\d{1,2})?)$";
            string ReplacementPattern = "$1-$3";
            string ToReplacePattern = @"((\.?\d{2})+)(\d)";

            input = Regex.Replace (input, ToReplacePattern, ReplacementPattern);
            Match result = Regex.Match (input, MatchPattern);
            if (result.Success) {
                inputField.text = input;
                inputField.caretPosition++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply say e.g. `inputField.caretPosition = input.Length - 1;` ?

Comment: Yes that would be a hotfix :D I thought this could be bug with regex and inputfield.

Comment: Actually I just tried and the behaviour stays the same ^^ might be a time issue and maybe you would need to wait a frame or manually force a repaint of the input field ... yup just tried again and there definitely is a huge delay until the caret actually is at the correct position ... seems like it is only updated after fulfilling a complete blink :D

Comment: I added this in LateUpdate() and it works for now ```inputField.MoveToEndOfLine (false, true);```

Comment: in general you also rather want to use `inputField.SetTextWithoutNotify` otherwise you always immediately get called `OnValueChanged` again ;)